# Помогите решить задачку на питоне

Tags: python, python-3.x

Напишите программу, которая бы «Подбрасывала» условную монету 100 раз и сообщала, сколько раз выпал
орел, а сколько - решка.
Проблема в том, что я не знаю как правильно показать сумму всех ста "подбросов" Я тут чего-то понаписал, скажите, правильно ли я мыслю, и все-таки помогите ее сделать) Неплохо было бы если бы вы могли посоветовать сайт с такими задачками.

```
coin= random.randint(1,2)
tries=1
side1=""
side2=""


while not tries == 100:
    side1=int()
    side2=int()
    coin= random.randint(1,2)
    tries = tries + 1
    if coin ==1:
        side1=coin+side1
    elif coin ==2:
        side2=coin+side2
        side2=int(side2/2)
    print(coin, side1, side2)
```

Comment: В чем проблема с этим кодом?

Comment: @Эникейщик я написал его, но он не работает, он показывает количество орлов и решек но делает это не в одной сумме.

Comment: Я ничего не понял. Изъясняйтесь более понятно.

Comment: @Эникейщик Этот код показывает их в ряд, то есть 0-1 1-0, и так сто раз, а мне нужно чтобы было проще, орел-49, решка-51

Comment: @ЭдуардВан создайте 2 переменные, которые будут хранить количество выпадений первой и второй стороны, прибавляйте к соответствующей переменной по 1 при выпадении.

Comment: А кто писал этот код?

Comment: Я писал этот код

Comment: @BrainSwitch а не подскажете как сохранить количество?

Comment: @ЭдуардВан в принципе даже одной достаточно, потому что общее количество выпадений известно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import random
tries = 0
eagle = 0
tail = 0

while tries < 100:
    coin = random.randint(0, 1)
    tries += 1
    if coin > 0:
        eagle +=1
    elif coin < 1:
        tail += 1
print(f"Монета подброшена {tries} раз")
print(f"Орел {eagle}")
print(f"Решка {tail}")
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
from random import randint

tries = 100
list_coin = []

while tries:
    list_coin.append(randint(1, 2))
    tries -= 1

print('рел - {}, решка - {}'.format( list_coin.count(1), list_coin.count(2)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно так:

```
from random import randint

heads = 0 # сколько раз выпал "орел"
tries = 100 # кол-во попыток
for _ in range(tries):
    # 0 - решка, 1 - орел
    if randint(0,1):
        heads +=1
tails = tries - heads # сколько раз выпала "решка"
print("Орёл: ", heads)
print("Решка: ", tails)
```